# A Difference on ViewControllers and Nibs

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder

I have been doing a lot of work on UIViewControlers and Nibs and notice there are two ways of doing it.

```
@class AController : UIViewController

[[AController alloc] initWithNibName:<name of nib> bundle:nil];
```

and the other way is that you make the File Owner the the UIViewController and link the View. All you have then do is

```
[[AController alloc] init];
```

or have it done else where, like in other nib files (I think).
For me, the latter is so much easier, so when explain how to load a nib file, why do they always use the first? And is there any difference, like performance-wise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`init` is just a convenience method that will load nib based on view-controller's name. If you provide the same name to `initWithNibName:bundle:`, then it is absolutely the same. There is practically no performance difference.

Comment: I don't name my nibs with the same name as the view controller, but it's good to know there is not performance difference.

Comment: It's a good practice to name them the same way, it's easier to navigate the project then.